# Enqueue script: link not working in page source

Tags: plugins, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, front-end, wp-register-script

I am using the [Front-End Editor plugin of Scribu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-editor/) at my website. I want to enqueue it, because I want to use it alongside my caching plugin, but that one only works when JS files are enqueued. The Front-End Editor plugin however, is not... so I decided to do that by myself.

I did this:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'editor.js', plugin_dir_url( 'front-end-editor/build/' ) . 'editor.js', array('jquery'), null, false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

And I tried removing the array and adding an `'all'`after false, but still: nothing.

With nothing, I mean: the file is enqueued and I can see it in my page source. All the paths are correct (checked a hundred times), but **it doesn't open it when I click on the link in page sourc**e. It just refreshes the page source page...

My question is: what am I doing wrong? Or is this plugin just not compatible? Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't open it when I click on the link in page source. It just refreshes the page source page

Are you **sure**? Sounds like you're getting the source for a WordPress 404 page. My spidey senses detect this is the problem:

```
plugin_dir_url( 'front-end-editor/build/' ) . 'editor.js'
```

...which isn't quite how it should be used ([see the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)), and you end up with:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/front-end-editor/editor.js
```

...see how the path is now broken? (`build` has been stripped)

Instead, use `plugins_url` ([see the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)):

```
plugins_url( 'front-end-editor/build/editor.js' )
```